# Excel out of resources from array formula

Tags: excel, resources, array-formulas

I have an excel file where I am trying to link rows with predecessor or successor dependencies (simplified MS project type links)

[image: excel example]

The formulas attempt to automatically calculate the successors from the predecessors.  The big challenge was with handling the merged cells in column A.  The formula is:

```
{=LARGE(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$a$1:$a$",SMALL(IF($C$2:$C$101=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("a",LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER($A$2:$A2),ROW($A$2:$A2)),1))),ROW(A$2:A$101)),ROW(A2)-LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER($A$2:$A2),ROW($A$2:$A2)),1)+1))),1)}
```

As you can see, this calculates the values correctly, but if I add iferror() to handle the error conditions, Excel complains that the function causes it to run out of resources.  Is there any way to get around this or to simplify my formula to avoid the issue?

Comment: Maybe you could use Conditional Formatting to format the font of the error cells to the same color as the interior color, effectively making it invisible.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - IMHO, using `;;;` as a custom number format is a much better method of making a cell's contents 'invisible' than formatting the font to match the cell fill color.

Comment: I've retyped your data and merged the cells in column A into single cells from 5 cell blocks and I cannot get your formula to work nor understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Jeeped I have not been able to get that to work when the result being hidden is an error value.  I just tried it again and failed.  I used a simple formula for CF `=iserror(a1)`; and entered `=0/0` into A1.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Yes, you are correct; you cannot use a custom number format to adjust an error value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if we replace all the INDIRECT(CONCATENATE()) references with the non volatile INDEX:

```
=IFERROR(LARGE($A$1:INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF($C$2:$C$101=INDEX(A:A,LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER($A$2:$A2),ROW($A$2:$A2)),1)),ROW(A$2:A$101)),ROW(A2)-LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER($A$2:$A2),ROW($A$2:$A2)),1)+1)),1),"")
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: @user162017 please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.